# Invariant subspaces of Frobenius automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

> Given finite field, is it true that any invariant subspace of its
>   Frobenius automorphism is a subfield?

Firstly, I know that $F_{p^k}$ is a subfield of $F_{p^n}$ if and only if $k$ divides $n$.

For the second, it seems that we shall use that if finite field is of characteristic $p$ then any element satisfies $x^p=x$.

However, I can't proceed to the final answer from this remarks. Can anyone explain me is it truth or not and why?

Comment: It is not true that every element of a field of characteristic $p$ satisfies $x^p = x$: only the elements of the minimal subfield do.

Comment: Characteristic pp means that $p=0$ i.e. $\underbrace{a+\ldots+a}_p = pa = 0$. So that $(a+b)^p =\sum_{n=0}^p {p \choose n} a^n b^{p-n} =a^p +b^p$ and $(a+b)^{p^k} = \sum_{n=0}^p {p^k \choose n} a^n b^{p^k-n} = a^{p^k} +b^{p^k}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}}$I understand the question to be

> Suppose the $\F_{p}$-subspace $V$ of the finite field $\F_{p^{n}}$ is invariant under the Frobenius automorphism. 
>   Is $V$ a subfield of $\F_{p^{n}}$?

The answer is **negative**.

Let $E = \F_{p^{6}}$.

Then $U = \F_{p^{2}}$, $W = \F_{p^{3}}$ are subfields of $E$, and thus $\F_{p}$-subspaces of $E$.

Then $V = U + W$ is an $\F_{p}$-subspace of $E$, which [has dimension $2 + 3 - 1 = 4$ over $\F_{p}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace#Sum), and thus order $p^{4}$, so that it is not a subfield of $E$.

However $V$ is invariant under the Frobenius automorphism, as $U$ and $W$ are.

Answer (score 3):

Andreas Caranti's answer gives a nice example. Another one that comes to mind right away is the kernel of the trace map. The trace is the function
$$tr:\Bbb{F}_{p^n}\to\Bbb{F}_p, tr(x)=x+x^p+x^{p^2}+\cdots+x^{p^{n-1}}.$$
We have $tr(x+y)=tr(x)+tr(y)$, so the kernel of the trace is a subspace.

Because we also have $tr(x^p)=tr(x)$, the kernel is stable under Frobenius.
Hence $\operatorname{Ker}(tr)$ is an $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ stable under Frobenius. [Edit: Thanks, Andreas!] This is not a subfield when $n>2$ because then $n-1\nmid n$. [/Edit]

You can also use images of linear combinations of (iterated) powers of the Frobenius to generate more examples. There will be overlap in images and kernels though. Possibly the best known example of such is the additive version of Hilbert's Satz 90: 
$$\operatorname{Ker}(tr)=\operatorname{Im}(\phi),$$
where $\phi=F-id$, i.e. $\phi(x)=x^p-x$ for all $x\in\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$.

Comment: Oh, **+1**, sure, that's more natural than mine, and allows for a smaller example. (Nitpick: take $n > 2$.)

Answer (score -1):

It seems that I found a proof. Denote our finite field of characteristic $p$ by $F_{p^n}$. Then set of all elements invariant under $x \mapsto x^p$ contains prime subfield $F_p$ and roots of the polynomial $t^p-t$, but $\vert F_p \vert = p$, so the invariant subset is exactly the prime subfield $F_p$ and the answer is yes.

Moreover, multiplication group $F_{p^n}^*$ is cyclic of order $p^n-1$ and by Lagrange theorem any its element has order $k \in \mathbb{N}$, where $k$ divides $p^n-1$.

Is everything correct?

Comment: No. Your proof does not make sense. You should start with a fixed subspace $V$ and show under the hypothesis that $\sigma(V) = V$ that $V$ is a field, i.e that it is stable by multiplication and inverse. What you said is true but it only show that $F_p$ is fixed by $\sigma$, which is weaker that your exercise.

Comment: @N.H. But for $a \in \mathbb{F}_p,\sigma(a) = a$. Thus, if $\sigma(V) = V$ then $\sigma(V \setminus \mathbb{F}_p) =V \setminus \mathbb{F}_p$ and hence $V \setminus \mathbb{F}_p$ is not a field. So the answer is no ?

Comment: $V \backslash \mathbb F_p$ is not a subspace.

Comment: @N.H. Why that ? We are seeing $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ as a $k$-dimensional $\mathbb{F}_{p}$-vector space so $\mathbb{F}_{p^k} \setminus \mathbb{F}_{p}$ is a subspace

Comment: $0$ is not in your "subspace".

Comment: @N.H. Yes, so I meant $V \setminus \mathbb{F}_{p}^*$

Comment: This is not a subspace again.

Comment: @N.H. With $\mathbb{F}_{p^k} = \mathbb{F}_{p}[x]/(h(x))$ for some irreducible polynomial $h$ of degree $k$, the subspaces are of the form $\{ \sum_{n \in I} a_n x^n, a_n \in \mathbb{F}_p\}$ with $I \subset \{0 \ldots k-1\}$. Removing $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ from $V$ means removing $0$ from $I$

Comment: $x+1$ and $x$ are in $V \backslash \mathbb F_p^*$ but $x + 1 - x = 1$ is not.

Comment: @N.H. Yes I meant the complementary of $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ in $V$ !

Comment: I admit operating with all those algebraic structures is hard to me

Comment: @N.H., thanks for the comment.

Let $V$ be an invariant subspace of Frobenius automorphism $\sigma$, $a,b,c,d \in V$ such that $\sigma(a)=c$ and $\sigma(b)=d$ ($a$ may be equal to $c$ or may not, similarly with $b$ and $d$).

Then $c\cdot d = \sigma(a)\cdot\sigma(b)=\sigma(ab)\in V$, so $V$ is stable under multiplication. $1=\sigma(1)=\sigma(a\cdot a^{-1})=\sigma(a)\cdot\sigma(a^{-1})=c\cdot c^{-1}$, so if $c \in V$, then $c^{-1}$ is also in $V$.

Is it really so easy or am I missing something important again?

Comment: Why $ab \in V$ ?